# how to work with nullable properties with communitytoolkit.mvvm in a MAUI project?

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I have an entry that is a numeric. it binds to a long? property. But when I delete the number of the entry, it is not null, it keep the last digit. It seems that when it is empty, the property is not notified.

What I would like to do is if the entry is empty, get null.

This is my code:

```
[ObservableProperty]
long? myProperty;
```

Thanks.